# DMX with Expansive Soils

Tags: basement, subfloor

I live in Colorado and have to deal with [expansive soil](https://coloradogeologicalsurvey.org/hazards/expansive-soil-rock/) caused by bentonite. Our basement slab is intentionally designed to float with the expansive soil and I have personally observed shifts in the slab up to ~2 inches (~5 cm) at my house. I don't expect we will ever have a perfectly level basement floor for any extended period of time; however, I was wondering if any of you have experience working with vinyl laminate flooring products like [DMX](https://dmx1step.com/) in such environments. Is DMX supported in areas with expansive soils? Are there other subfloor types and/or considerations I should be aware of?

Comment: What the heck is DMX?

Comment: It's a vinyl laminate. I updated my question to include a link to their product page. I'm not completely sold on using DMX, the way. I just liked that it looks simple to install.

Comment: Vinyl laminate flooring that is?

Comment: Included the fact that DMX is a vinyl laminate flooring into the question itself to clear up a lot of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

DMX seems like it’s for removing moisture ABOVE the slab. It doesn’t have anything to do with the slab “moving” due to expansive soil.

When we want to control expansive soil we over excavate (removing the expansive soils) and install a layer of crushed rock. The deepest we’ve ever over excavated and installed a layer of crushed rock is 8’. The thinnest is 2’.

We also install perf pipe near the bottom of the crushed rock layer at about 10’ - 25’ on center, depending on the subsurface moisture conditions, and the tie them all together and send them over an embankment.

If you have an above slab moisture problem, install a perimeter drain, but make sure it’s about 8” (or more) below the top of the slab.